# Concatenating DataFrames through function calls

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a single row dataframe (df) and add it to the end of another dataframe (df_all) using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

global df_all    
df_all = pd.DataFrame()

def save_data(df):
     df_all = pd.concat([df, df_all], axis=0)
     display(df_all)
     return df_all

def opt():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))  # one row data
    display(df)
    save_data(df)
```

Using this loop I suppose to get 3 rows are saved to df_all. But I am getting an error message (local variable 'df_all' referenced before assignment)

```
for i in range (3):
    opt()
    display(df_all)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe in functions that rely on global variables—it just isn't good hygiene.

Functions should be pure. First, define your `opt` function. This just generates `df` and nothing more.

```
def opt():
    df = ...  # df is generated here
    return df
```

Next, define `save_data`. Well, I've renamed it to `augment` to be more in line with what you're doing. This concatenates two DataFrames together.

```
def augment(df, df_new):
    return pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1)
```

Finally, your mainloop. All state is maintained here, not in the functions—

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(3):
    df_all = augment(df_all, opt())
    display(df_all)
```

Answer (score 0):

move `global df_all` to `save_data(df)` block. like below

```
def save_data(df):
    global df_all    
    df_all = pd.concat([df, df_all], axis=0)
    display(df_all)
    return df_all
```

Comment: Recommending globals, even if the OP is asking for it, is something I don't condone.

Comment: Agree with you. I just fix the bug, but didn't consider whether this is a good way.

Comment: Thanks, Lambda. It works. I don't know how I did this silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach avoids use of global variable. Pass df_all as an argument to opt().

```
def save_data(df, df_all):
    df_all = pd.concat([df, df_all], axis=0)
    return df_all

def opt(df_all):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))  # one row data
    df_all = save_data(df, df_all)
    return df_all

df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(3):
    df_all = opt(df_all)
    display(df_all)
```

Comment: This is effectively my answer, except with a argument here instead of there.